# Inputting the Uniform Series Compound Amount formula

Tags: c++, exponent

The formula is (1+i)^n-1 /(i)):

I'm having trouble with inputting the exponent: 
How Do I use the exponent function? Can anyone assist me in this or provide me with an example if they misunderstand.
Thanks.

```
 F = ((1+i)exp(7)-1)/1);
 cout << The gain is: " << F << endl;
```

Comment: I suspect the brackets are wrong.  However converting what you typed in your formula :
`std::pow(1+i, n) - 1/i`

Comment: Okay thank you so much .